# Iterating over Dataframe columns to plot Histogram

Tags: python, pandas, types, data-visualization, histogram

```
%matplotlib inline
for column in df.columns:
if df[column].dtype =="int64":
    df[column].hist(title=column)
else:
    df[column].plot(kind="bar", title=column)

AttributeError: 'Rectangle' object has no property 'title'
```

I would like to print Histogram whether the dtype is int and a barplot whether the dtype is object but the code isn't working.

Comment: "Isn't working" is a very broad statement. What specific problem are you having? Tips: thte `title` argument is only available in newer versions of pandas. Check your version

Comment: Isn't working mean that returns AttributeError: 'Rectangle' object has no property 'title' and not the plots

Comment: I tried to remove the title and then it raises this new error :TypeError: no numeric data to plot

Comment: no numeric data to plot because you cant bar plot a string , one of your other column are of type object and you trying to apply a barplot

Comment: @AlessandroMondin i just edited my answer to take in account object type by using seaborn count plot check it out

Answer (score 0):

Try to slice your columns at start and you need subplot/subplots to plot multiple graphs

```
import seaborn as sns

numeric_columns = df.select_dtypes(include=['int64','float64']).columns
n_rows = 2
n_cols= 2

for i, column in enumerate(df.columns,1):
    plt.subplot(n_rows,n_cols,i)
    if column in numeric_columns:
        df[column].plot(kind="hist", title=column)
    else:
        sns.countplot(df[column])
```

And as mentioned by Code Different you want get of the title arguement if you are using an older pandas version